# Is there a way to detect, via SOQL query or describe, whether Email-to-Case is turned on in an org?

Tags: email2case

**Problem statement**: I need to determine, given only API access to an org, whether or not that org has Email-to-Case turned on.

**Known Options**: It's definitely possible by doing a Metadata API retrieve, but I would prefer not to do so because it's slow, invasive, and heavy-weight.

I have never used Email-to-Case hands-on, and am not deeply familiar with the feature. My understanding is that the Email Message object and its schema are not a reliable indicator because it's activated by both Email-to-Case *and* Enhanced Email.

I'm looking for a way to determine, with a Describe call or SOQL query, whether or not this feature is turned on. Are there any schema changes introduced by this feature that I can spot? As far as I've been able to determine, the configuration for the feature is not stored in an sObject I can query, but I'd be delighted to be incorrect.

One candidate seems to be the field `Case.ThreadId` - are there other features that also expose/use this field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at [EmailServicesAddress](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailservicesaddress.htm) and [EmailServicesFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailservicesfunction.htm).

```
SELECT Id, FunctionName, isActive
FROM EmailServicesFunction
```

The above will return a row with the following info when E2C is activated:

- `FunctionName` = `EmailToCase`
- `IsActive` = `true`

```
SELECT Id,EmailDomainName,IsActive 
FROM EmailServicesAddress 
WHERE Function.FunctionName = 'EmailToCase'
```

The above returns the Routing Addresses set up for Email-to-Case if you need to check that these have been configured (for this to return rows, they'll also need to enable `On-Demand Service`).

Comment: Excellent - thank you, Kris! I suspect that the project I am working on also requires that a Routing Address be configured. I'll double-check that.

Comment: I added another caveat after testing in a scratch org. If you just enable E2C, the routing addresses do not show up in the query. Only when you enable on-demand service do they show up as I outlined.

Comment: I have ondemand service enabled but this query always returns 0 rows. any suggestions?

Comment: And you have routing addresses set up under `Email2Case`?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Yes I had routing addresses setup & query was giving 0 rows. However i found the issue & it is because of sandbox refresh. After the refresh the Email Services Address for a Routing Address becomes empty. So i just had to edit and save the routing address & this generated a new one. After this step, the query returned results.